# Allocating a struct and saving a string in it

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I'm having issues with getting create to hold firstE here:

```
struct node {
    char * data;
    struct node * next;
};

struct node * createList(char * firstE){
  struct node *create;

  create = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  create->data = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  strcpy(create->data, firstE);
  create->next = NULL;
  return create;
}
```

I'm having a problem with the memory allocation for `create->data`. I am trying to get it to hold the value of `FirstE` but I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 2):

I have to guess your problem since there is no struct definition. Your second `malloc` allocates memory for a field of the same type as the struct. But because you use `strcpy` to copy from the function argument, I suggest this line is incorrect, it allocates the wrong amount of memory

```
create->data = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
strcpy(create->data, firstE);
```

Since you copy the string argument to this field, I suggest this

```
create->data = malloc(1 + strlen(firstE));
strcpy(create->data, firstE);
```

The `1 +` is to allow for the string terminator.

Comment: struct node {
      char * data;
      struct node * next;
    };

Comment: I apologize for not including the struct def. Thanks alot for help.

Comment: @Luis: welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the introductory [tour] to familiarize yourself with the basics. If an answer helped you out, you can [mark it as accepted](What should I do when someone answers my question?). (In fact, doing that is strongly preferred over commenting "thanks".)